# Adding a key(Path) to JSON-Object with sharedb and json0-ot-type

Tags: javascript, operational-transform, sharedb

I am currently working with sharedb (https://share.github.io/sharedb/) and the operationel transformation type json0 (https://github.com/ottypes/json0).
I need to add a key (path) to a JSON object afterwards, which should be shared via sharedb.

For example, the key "key2" should be added to the following JSON object:

```
{
   key1: 'some_value',
}
```

Unfortunately, according to the documentation of json0 (https://github.com/ottypes/json0), there is no operation for this, which surprises me a lot.
How can I add a new key that will be recognized by sharedb?
Simply adding the key (path) locally makes sharedb not recognize it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs you shared](https://github.com/ottypes/json0#summary-of-operations) say:

> `{p:[path,key], oi:obj}` inserts the object `obj` into the object at `[path]` with key `key`.

So you'd want to use that `oi` ("object insert") op shape:

```js
const op = [{p: ['key2'], oi: 'some_other_value'}]
doc.submitOp(op)
```

Comment: I was missing the `[]` around the path property value. Only giving the string. Thank you for the tip! BTW, you can do the same using the json1 class methods : 
`const json1 = require('ot-json1');
    const operation = json1.replaceOp(['counter'], 'old', 'newValue');
    doc.submitOp([operation]);`
More on that here:  https://github.com/ottypes/json1